#  C - V characteristics of MOS capacitors for different material

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, semiconductors

For C-V curve below for 3 different materials, (Si, InAs, InSb). What material will be corresponding to curve A/B/C?

My understanding is that C is inversely proportional to the dielectric constant in the inversion region. As a result, Si has the smallest dielectric constant and therefore matches with C.
InAs = B InSb = C[image]

Is my understanding correct? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are correct, if they all have the same cros sectional area and same doping concentration in the semiconductor.

For a MOS capacitor, the capacitance value in inversion region is given by the the series combination of insulator capacitance (\$C_{ox}\$) and the semiconductor capacitance in inversion (\$C_{s}\$). Since all the three capacitors have same capacitance in the accumulation region, \$C_{ox}\$ values are same. \$C_s\$ depends on dielectric constant of the semiconductor (\$\epsilon_s\$) and doping in the material. So if the doping is can be assumed to be same, then MOS capacitor with least \$C_s\$ will have lowest capacitance.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I found the equation Cs = (W_d / ϵ ) ^-1,  if ϵ decrease then Cs decrease. this matches what you suggested!

Comment: @tinyhulk note that \$W_d\$ has a \$\sqrt{\epsilon}\$ term inside.